# Switching Permissions of User Files

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to Bash and trying to write a find command that finds all files that don't have read, write, or execute permissions for the user, and then changes the mode to enable read access.

I've tried a few different ways including:
`find . ! -perm /u+rwx | -exec chmod u+r {} \;`

Am I on the right track?

Comment: your requirement seems confused. Why search for NOT(write | Execute) when you're not changing the permissions to match? Also, you don't want a `|` char in a `find` command, except at the end, where another  process will consume the "found" data.  Also not sure about the leading `/` for `/u+rwx` but your `man find` research may have shown you that your version needs that. Otherwise it seem good. Test, and retest! Good luck.

Comment: Also, doesn't `! -perm /u+rws` mean all of those must be unset, not just any of them as your problem description implies (to my reading). Good luck again!

Comment: Your description of the task is unclear. Include a [mre].

Comment: `! -perm /u+rwx` matches the files with *all* permissions for the user are unset. Is that what you want? If so, you are on the right track but just drop the `|`.

Comment: based on your written description of your problem, I think you want `find . ! \( -perim /u+r -o -perm /u+w -o -perm /u+x \) -print0 | xargs -0 echo "chmod u+r`. I don't have a way to test it, you may need to change the `-o`s to `-a`s. And researching how the cmd works will get you a really good intro into the `find` (and `xargs`) worlds. See possibly https://grymoire.com/Unix/Find.html . Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, take the Grymoire's find as a baseline. That is very Sun/Unix centric view of things and modern Linux's have many more features. Not sure where there is a comprehensive tutorial though. Good luck.

Comment: How can you find files when you don't have permissions for that? And why not just add permissions to all files, wouldn't this lead in same result?

Comment: why not add permission to all files in the said directory   `find . -type f | xargs chmod u+r` . Note, `-type f` will only look for files

Comment: @BhaskarTallamraju that won't work for non-trivial file names. `-exec chmod +r {} +` is recommended for that

Comment: got it, thanks @alecxs